# Jackson library error calling 'writeValue' function

Tags: java, json, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to use Jackson for converting string to JSON object in java. I have both [jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.5.3/jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar) file and [maven project](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/archive/master.zip) of the library, with which I tried one by one but both giving error while calling `writeValue` function. Error says -

```
The type com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I have correctly added the library to build path.
After looking at [eclipse-error-indirectly-referenced-from-required-class-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547162/eclipse-error-indirectly-referenced-from-required-class-files) ,I realized that the problem is because of missing  `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator` class file.So Which jar file I missed to add to build path?. Tried by adding the maven project on build path too- same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find which jar contains the required file, you can always use http://search.maven.org and search for the class prefixing it with `fc:`, like this:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3Acom.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator

Looks like you're missing jackson-core jar on your classpath.

Comment: thanks after searching I found out that jackson-core has class `jackson-core` but when I tried to import `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator` , it din't show up.

Comment: Did you add jackson-core to your maven `dependencies`? Under Eclipse you probably need to refresh the maven configuration or rebuild the project.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have in your path jackson-databind and jackson-core

Comment: I have jackson core also added, but there is no class called `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator` to import.

Answer (score 0):

build path is used during compile.  You need to set up the Deployment Assembly for run time classpath (under project settings, look for Deployment Assembly )