# java error says JOptionPane cannot be resolved, didn't use JOptionPane

Tags: java, jframe, actionlistener, actionevent

I'm kind of a beginner and I was using a tutorial to make a simple program that displays text fields on a JFrame. I didn't use a JLayeredPane in the whole project, but I still get this error that says, "The type javax.swing.JLayeredPane cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files." Why do I get this error?
Here's the code (there's two classes):

second class:

```
  package eventHandlerTutorial;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class secondClass extends JFrame
{
private JTextField item1;
private JTextField item2;
private JTextField item3;
private JPasswordField passwordField;
public secondClass()
   {
    super("The title");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    item1=new JTextField(10);
    add(item1);
    item2=new JTextField("enter text here");
    add(item2);
    item3=new JTextField("uneditable",20);
    item3.setEditable(false);
    add(item3);
    passwordField=new JPasswordField("mypass");
    add(passwordField);
    theHandler handler=new theHandler();
    item1.addActionListener(handler);
    item2.addActionListener(handler);
    item3.addActionListener(handler);
    passwordField.addActionListener(handler);
   }
private class theHandler implements ActionListener
        {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
            String string="";
            if(event.getSource()==item1)
                string=String.format("field 1: %s",event.getActionCommand());
            else if(event.getSource()==item2)
                string=String.format("field 2: %s",event.getActionCommand());
            else if (event.getSource()==item3)
                string=String.format("field 3: %s",event.getActionCommand());
            else if(event.getSource()==passwordField)
                string=String.format("password field is: %s",event.getActionCommand());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,string);         
            }
        }
}
```

main class:

```
 package eventHandlerTutorial;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class mainClass 
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  secondClass sc=new secondClass();
  sc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  sc.setSize(350,100);
  sc.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: save and recompile.but what is tuna?

Comment: read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547162/eclipse-error-indirectly-referenced-from-required-class-files

Comment: How you compiling/running your code?  It seems fine for me

Comment: tuna is what the guy in the tutorial named his second class. So every time this code says secondClass, my own code says tuna. I tried to change tuna to secondClass in this question to make it more simple, but I guess I missed part of it.  I edited the question so it's fixed now.

Comment: @SprungLake9036 if you are using a ide eclipse/netbeans .try to clean and build your project

Comment: @Fast Snail cleaning the project fixed everything. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error is explained:
"... cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.".

Another thing is, in your question you are saying "JOptionPane"
and
in explanation you are saying "JLayeredPane".

Sometimes (because of IDE errors) you are suppose to import manually.
Add

```
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
```

manually.
and check it out.

if, still you face issue,
try to clean the project.