# Cucumber - The type cucumber.api.SnippetType cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Getting the above error in the runner class. Please check the screenprint below: -
[image]

When I am trying to change the JDK to 1.10, it is getting changed automatically to 1.5 JRE automatically after Maven Update. I am not sure that this error is interrelated with the JRE version or not. Can anyone help me to resolve this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547162/eclipse-error-indirectly-referenced-from-required-class-files

Comment: The other question doesn't provide the full details and there is no answer associated with it.