# The type com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3$Builder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, protocol-buffers

I have been doing my project and all the sudden eclipse started to give this error saying

```
The type com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3$Builder cannot be resolved.
```

It is indirectly referenced from required .class files where we declare the package. I have tried adding `com.google.protobuf-2.4.0.jar` to build path but it did not work. Please help and here's the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Class you are using is not in classpath, please try adding into classpath. Also after adding  please clean the project (from Project->Clean...).

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547162/eclipse-error-indirectly-referenced-from-required-class-files

Answer (score 2):

`com.mysql.cj.x.protobuf.MysqlxSql.StmtExecute` is not on the classpath so remove this import

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting Protobuf generated files to be available, then ensure that you have added the Protobuf library to your project.

Gradle example:

```
implementation group: 'com.google.protobuf', name: 'protobuf-java', version: googleProtobufVersion
```

Maven example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>${googleProtobufVersion}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps at such a later date. But i also faced something similar.

I found that I imported this by mistake

```
import com.mysql.cj.x.protobuf.MysqlxDatatypes.Array;
```

After removing this line, it works fine.

In your case you need to remove the import

```
com.mysql.cj.x.protobuf.MysqlxSql.StmtExecute
```

Replace it with the relevant import.

Answer (score -1):

This is due to the missing dependency of gRPC protobuf. Add this dependency to your pom.xml and this should solve your problem.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Lastly, do maven -> project update