# eclipse projects build path is driving me nuts

Tags: eclipse, java-11, eclipse-jdt

I have this number of apps/libraries which I set up in different projects.  Development and refactorings are mostly simultaneous so I don't want to "build library, deploy to lib folder of depending projects, rebuild depending projects".

At the leaf of the dependency tree is CLIENT.  I only have the JRE library in Libraries->Module Path.  Builds just fine.  (CLIENT has a module.info that exports its packages.)

One depending app is DBROWSER.  Requires only JRE+CLIENT, so I have CLIENT in Projects->Module Path and JRE in Libraries->Module Path.  Builds fine.  DBROWSER has a module.info that requires what it needs, and exports nothing (it's a main GUI app.)

Other depending app is SERVER.  Requires only JRE+CLIENT, so I have CLIENT in Projects->Module Path and JRE in Libraries->Module Path.  Refuses to build.  Error message is "The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.util.Set. Fix the build path then try building this project".  I've tried cleaning dozens of times, only results in seemingly random shifting around to other error messages, mostly "could not be resolved" and "indirectly referenced from existing .class files".

What am I missing ?

EDIT

I also found this

"It sounds like this has been a known issue (Bug 67414)that was resolved in 3.0 ... someone has commented that it's occurring for them in 3.4 as well.

In the mean time, the work around is to remove the JRE System Library from the project and then add it back again."

at

[Eclipse error: indirectly referenced from required .class files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547162/eclipse-error-indirectly-referenced-from-required-class-files)

Didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

From the symptom I'd guess that this is https://bugs.eclipse.org/547181 which is fixed in current milestone / integration builds, so please try installing [2019-09 M2](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2019-09/m2)