# The type org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4, powermockito

I have following jars in my class path

1. powermock-module-junit4-2.0.7.jar
2. powermock-api-mockito2-2.0.7.jar
3. powermock-api-support-1.4.9.jar
4. mockito-core-2.8.9.jar
5. junit-4.10.jar

I have imported following classes.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.doReturn;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.spy;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.verifyPrivate;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
```

Then I am getting following error while executing my test class

```
The type org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

PS: I  am not using any framework like spring boot
Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse error: indirectly referenced from required .class files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547162/eclipse-error-indirectly-referenced-from-required-class-files)

Comment: No, because it was working fine previously. Only when I added following jars and tried to do junit power mockito testing, this error occured.

Comment: And if it's the same then I need to understand what is the other dependency it is looking for as I've added support jar also

Answer (score 2):

Try using the 2.0.7 version of  powermock-api-support jar. If you are adding jars manually to classpath, delete that jar and rebuild the classpath. Else if you are using dependency management tool like maven/gradle, try deleting the target/build folders and doing a rebuild of the project.
Often this is a problem with Eclipse , it uses stale information.

Comment: Hi Abhinaba, I tried with  2.0.7 version of powermock-api-support jar, then also same issue. I am not using maven/gradle I am using ANT build. Any other fix ?